# Problem Trying to Consolidate Styles in WPF App

Tags: c#, wpf

I apparently don't understand how styles are defined and used in WPF. If I include the following style in, say, the resources for a Grid containing TextBlocks:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
</Style>
```

it makes all the TextBlocks have the desired attributes.

But if I put it in App.xaml so that I can use the default application wide, say like this (note that I'm using MergedDictionaries because I have to include a bunch of other MahApps resource dictionaries, not shown here):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

it still defines the default for how TextBlocks are displayed at design time (in the designer)...but the app crashes upon launch with the error message:

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x80131501
  Message='Set property 'System.Windows.Style.BasedOn' threw an exception.' Line number '72' and line position '18'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at J4JSoftware.RetirementModeling.MainWindow.InitializeComponent() in C:\Programming\RetirementModeling\RetirementWPF\ui\windows\MainWindow.xaml:line 1

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Windows.Style'.
```

which makes no sense to me.

Comment: How do you use `BasedOn` and/or set the `Style` of your window?

Answer (score 0):

#### General

First, that error message doesn't seem to be related to the context of the question, mate. Check or add your MainWindow.xaml code here.
If you want to apply the style globally, add your style directly to the ResourceDictionary tag, not to the MergedDictionaries of the App.xaml.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/{assembly};component/{resource_path}.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

#### Bundle

If the style is in a separate resource file, it will still work due to the bundle of all specified resources.
App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/{assembly};component/{resource_path}.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

ResourceDictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: The first block of XAML code is, in fact, from MainWindow.xaml, under the (sole/containing) Grid control.